# Can I change the datatype and max length of a column in Table B that I'm creating with a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT FROM Table A?

Tags: sql, db2, create-table

I would like to have the converted date formats to be in the ResultB Table instead of the CHAR type dates and I was looking for a way to do this inside the create table state in 1 go.

I have successfully created a new Table ResultB with a subset of data from source Table SourceA.
There is a column UPLSTD (CHAR type) that contains dates, in order to compare with the current date I converted the CHAR type dates with a to_date function, this also works.

```
CREATE TABLE ResultB AS
            (SELECT UPUPRF,
                    UPTEXT,
                    UPLSTD
                    FROM SourceA
                    WHERE to_date(SUBSTR(DIGITS(UPLSTD), 27, 6), 'RRMMDD') < CURRENT_DATE - 10 DAYS)
            WITH DATA
```

I want the output to be:

```
UPUPRF    UPTEXT    UPLSTD (DATE Format)
------   --------   --------------------
ABCD      ABCDEFG   2019-08-21
```

But the actual is:

```
UPUPRF    UPTEXT    UPLSTD (CHAR Format)
------   --------   --------------------
ABCD      ABCDEFG   190821
```

Comment: Hi, to be exact, IBM DB2 for i

Comment: i guess it should work like an insert as `create table name ( col1 varchar, col2 ..) as select col1, to_char(col2)...`

Comment: The `DATE` data type does not have any intrinsic format, so your intent for it to have the "DATE format" is confusing. Do you want the resulting `UPLSTD` to be a character data type formatted as you describe, or do you want it to be a true `DATE`?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, Thanks for your tip, I'll try that out.

Comment: @mustaccio, Hi, thanks for that, I didn't know that, I assumed a DATE type would have a choice how it is formatted (like YY-MM-DD or Julian date, ....).
To answer your question, I'm more interested to have it in a certain format so YYYY-MM-DD in the ResultB table.

Comment: Thanks all for your contributions! Your feedback got me thinking in the right direction and it's working flawlessly now! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an expressions you can use to convert your CHAR field to a true DATE format.

DATE(TO_DATE(ACHARDATE, 'YYMMDD'))

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could use this option, but it's more confusing in my opinion:

```
DATE('20' || SUBSTR(ACHARDATE,1,2) ||'-' ||
     SUBSTR(ACHARDATE,3,2) ||'-' ||
     SUBSTR(ACHARDATE,5,2))
```

Answer (score -1):

i guess it should work like an insert as `create table name ( col1 varchar, col2 ..) as select col1, to_char(col2)...`

```
     CREATE TABLE ResultB (UPURF 
      VARCHAR(20), UPTEXT 
       VARCHAR(20) 
     , UPLSTD VARCHAR(20))AS
        (SELECT UPUPRF,
                UPTEXT,
                TO_CHAR(UPLSTD)
                FROM SourceA
                WHERE 
          to_date(SUBSTR(DIGITS(UPLSTD), 
         27, 6), 'RRMMDD') < 
         CURRENT_DATE - 10 DAYS)
        WITH DATA
```